# shinyproxy: how to bypass login page feature to avoid logging twice?

Tags: shinyproxy

I already have a [login page](http://eedm.wistro.com/LoginPage.aspx) in my organization which access users' ID and password from HR system (see below).

[image]

My question is: how can I bypass the built-in login feature of shinyproxy and the navbar above my app(see picture below)?

[image]
Thanks for any suggestion and comment.

Answer (score 3):

I find the solution as follows:

Just set `authentication: none` and `hide-navbar: true` in `proxy` in `application.yml`, and that's it.

```
proxy:
  title: Standalone Docker Engine with euler Example
  port: 8080
  authentication: none
  hide-navbar: true
```